# JMeter - Single URL redirects to multiple URLs fails during load test

Tags: jmeter

I am running the test which includes multiple redirection (max of 5) of urls within the requests. When I try to run for single user, it is working fine without any issues. I am getting the base url which redirects to multiple using regular expression extractor.

When I try to run for 100 users for certain period of time, it fails in the redirection (redirects upto 4th url) and getting below response code & message for that final redirected url.

> Response code: 404
>
> Response message: Not Found

I have checked the request parameters and it is passing correctly as expected.

Could you please anyone help us to check why this situation happens?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it happens only during the load my expectation is that this is a problem, connected with concurrency, i.e. you found a bottleneck which prevents successful redirection when number of actual users exceeds certain amount.

It might be the case your application gets overloaded and cannot fully fulfil the responses. In order to get to the bottom of the issue consider the following steps:

1. Check your application logs for any suspicious entries
2. Ensure your application has enough headroom to operate in terms of resources (CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, etc.). The malfunction can be caused by simple lack of resources. You can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) for these purposes.
3. Check your middleware configuration and logs, it might be the case the error happens on the [load balancer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)) or [application server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_server)

In addition:

1. Check JMeter engine(s) is(are) not overloaded
2. Check [*jmeter.log*](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file, if the error happens on JMeter side - most probably it will be something there

Comment: Thanks much Dmitri T. I was waiting for your reply since I posted this question :) I could not see any error in the jmeter log. Could you please share me the link on how to check & make sure that JMeter engines are not overlaoded?